# Xammp MySQL wont start after windows update

Tags: mysql, xampp

So this is the second time today I have this issue on different computers. the first time I was able to resolve the issue of MySQL not starting by changing the port from `3306` to `3308` and replacing the files in `xammp/mysql/data/mysql` with the ones from `xammp/mysql/backup/mysql`

But this did not work for the second PC, the only difference I can think of is I changed the php.ini file but after reverting my changes the issue still remains.

Xampp MySQL LOG:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size= 16M 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active. 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ... 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB. 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 5949299252; transaction id 85826 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 
2020-10-27  9:32:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Windows event log:

```
 Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used;
 so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!!
 Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
 Could not find target log during relay log initialization
 Failed to open the relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d10@002d02@002014@003a20@003a58@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.000001'
 (relay_log_pos 4)
 Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d10@002d02@002014@003a20@003a58@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info' failed
 Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
 Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
 Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
 Failed to initialize multi master structures
 Aborting
```

Recap of what I tried

- Replace MySQL files with backup files
- Stop MySQL services and restart using xammp
- Change the port
- run `services.msc` start MySQL service then start on xammp
- Delete aria_log.0000000001
- Rename ibdata1

Anyone know what is causing this issue?

Comment: You need to show us the error log or find an error in the windows event logs - what you copied in does not contain any errors.

Comment: @Shadow Added windows event log